# IDE for MSIL

Tags: ide, cil, ilide

There's any number of questions about MSIL on SO but none that directly answer this.

I've been using [Textpad](http://www.textpad.com/) which does have a syntax definition file for MSIL and then using ILASM in a command prompt window.

I did find a reference to ILIDE but the link is broken.

Is there an IDE or add-on / plugin to Visual Studio / Eclipse for MSIL that allows syntax highlighting, intellisense, code completion, debugging etc.?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/748701/stuck-with-ilide too please, If you try and get around that please let me know! tx – Peter

Answer (score 4):

Use [MonoDevelop](http://www.monodevelop.com/)

You can build specially MSIL projects. It's very useful for these issues, also you can use it in both Windows and Linux. What is better than this? :)

Comment: When you try to download MonoDevelop now what you download is Xamarin Studio. And it does not seem to have any support for MSIL projects. I'm sure it used to work before when MonoDevelop and Xamarin were a different things, but it does not seem to work any longer.

Answer (score 3):

I made an extension for Visual Studio 2010 that supports syntax highlighting for IL files (.il) and includes projects with full debugging support for C#, F# and Visual Basic that support embedding and calling IL code directly.

[IL Support extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/44034a7b-143d-4b51-b7bc-99aa656ba137)

Enjoy!

Comment: Works great ! Please keep supporting your extension!

Answer (score 2):

I have exactly  the same question!

I have found ilide eventually :

http://nida.se/ilide/

(note : strangely, some links to ilide are broken, some of them even mentioning earlier links that are broken , but then supply a link that's broken too.  I was able to dowload it and Installed it succesfully from the link above though).

further   : 
http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=112895

seems  a very good debugger.

cheers, ph

Comment: The tool is absolutely rubbish. It's too fragile.

Answer (score 2):

[xacc.ide](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xacc) has syntax highlighting for MSIL, and another odd 20 .NET languages.

See some screenshots [here](http://xacc.wordpress.com/screenshots/).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can do it in [#develop IDE.](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/)

No intellisense though.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, Visual Studio will give you debugging, if you assemble with /debug.

I think MS had a demo or sample of some VS plugin that helped a bit with IL. I'm not sure what it was named or if it was released.