# Stuck with ILIDE

Tags: ide, cil, ilide

I'm trying desperately to find a (good, even any?) IDE for MSIL. (For that c : [IDE for MSIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640583/ide-for-msil))

I thought I found one with ILIDE, but when debugging my code I always (it's not depending on the code) get :

> SandDock]TD.SandDock.ControlLayoutSystem::OnMouseMove(System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs

When I don't use the mouse (since it's apparently triggered by e mouse-over)
I get :

`System.NullReferenceException` from 'debugger 3' without any additional info.

Did anyone use the program (3.0) with more success?